# How do you capture the Host IP address where Webdriver test is executing?

Tags: java, selenium

My Junit4/Java webdriver smoke test runs on a VM on windows 7 on FF23.0. I'm able to print the hostname/URL of the VM machine using:

```
 InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 System.out.println(IP.toString());
```

How would you capture the IP address stored in the host file on the VM where my smoke test is being executed.

Thank you,
Hamid

Answer (score 0):

I'd urge you to use a dedicated service.  There are many ways to do this, but what i'd recommend is to use one of your internal servers if you have them.

A simple 1 lined php script would work:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['remote_addr']; ?>
```

and have your test machine just fetch that. (this is how I can detect where all of my EC2 nodes are)

Answer (score 0):

Read the hosts file in and find the IP address in the string?

```
private static final String HOSTS_FILE_LOCATION = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts";


static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
throws IOException 
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}
```